# How can I change the JIRA administrator password in JIRA 4.2?

Tags: jira

I use JIRA for ticketing. I want to change the admin's username and password. I searched and found this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Retrieving+the+JIRA+Administrator):

```
select child_name, directory_id from cwd_membership where parent_name='jira-administrators';

update cwd_user set credential='uQieO/1CGMUIXXftw3ynrsaYLShI+GTcPS4LdUGWbIusFvHPfUzD7CZvms6yMMvA8I7FViHVEqr6Mj4pCLKAFQ==' where user_name='XXXX'`;
```

but I don't have the `cwd_user` table or the `cwd_membership` table in my database.

How can I reset my JIRA admin's password?

Comment: What version of JIRA?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a password reset according to the [documentation applicable to your version of JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA042/Retrieving+the+JIRA+Administrator), namely this:

```
update userbase set password_hash='uQieO/1CGMUIXXftw3ynrsaYLShI+GTcPS4LdUGWbIusFvHPfUzD7CZvms6yMMvA8I7FViHVEqr6Mj4pCLKAFQ==' where username='XXXX';
```

The above query will set the password for the user named "XXXX" to the word "sphere". Don't forget to restart JIRA after running this query.

If you fall into any of the other use cases (don't know the admin username, there is no admin user, etc) then the above documentation link spells out all of the other possibilities.